# How to perform Split and Stringbuilding in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, string-building

I'm a SQL acolyte, spending most of my time in Powershell. So for the purposes of this, I shall express myself thusly.  Basically, I have a column of FullName, that contains `FirstName LastName`, and I want it restructured to `LastName, Firstname` in a `SELECT` query.

If I wasn't clear enough, in Powershell I would do this:

```
$string = "John Smith"
$split = $string.Split(' ')
$builder = "$($split[0]), $($split[1])"
```

How does one accomplish this in SQL?

Comment: which sql server version?

Comment: What if someone's full name is `John Paul Van Der Veere`? Is it okay if it splits on the wrong space, since that's what would have happened in your Powershell script?

Comment: Yes, the column I'm dealing with is exclusively First Last without additional names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is nice and consistent, you can use a combination of the [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186323.aspx) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187748.aspx) functions:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(FullName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName)) AS FirstName,
    SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName)+1, LEN(FullName)) AS LastName
FROM NamesTable
```

Now if you want to join them back together, just use some string concatentation:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName)+1, LEN(FullName))
    + ', ' +
    SUBSTRING(FullName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName))
FROM NamesTable
```

Comment: Would that not separate them into two columns? How would I combine them into one, separated by a comma and space?

Comment: Yes, but I thought it would be fairly obvious how to concatenate them together again - I've added the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server 2016.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = 'clothing,road,,touring,bike'  

SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

Comment: In your DECLARE statement, is there a way to make that the content of a column I am querying? As opposed to doing a static assignment?

Comment: yes. SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT((select UserName from dbo.Users), '@')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';